# PHP $_GET('') issue. Very simple but I can't fix

Tags: php

I'm developing a script to grab some information from an external url. But I'm having issues with my hosting and script is returning "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden" so I did a very simple script to find about this issue and got same result.

when I go to ?url=http://youtube.com or ?url=http://google.com or what ever ?url=url, it is echoing variable value.

but when I'm visiting ?url=http://tiny.cc or ?url=http://adf.ly (found only these two for now), I'm getting "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden" (Discovered with firebug; displaying a blank page)

Thank you.

CODE:

```
<?php
  $get_url = $_GET['url'];
  if ( isset ( $get_url ) && $get_url != '' )
    echo $get_url;
  else
    echo 'Please enter "?url=anything" at the end of the URL.';
?>
```

Comment: Check your `.htaccess`. I don't think it's getting as far as your PHP script.

Comment: BTW you should check `$_GET['URL]` for existence, not `$get_url`!

Comment: It got basically nothing with PHP as it your httpd that returns 403 not PHP

Comment: @lc. yeah, you're right. I've just tested the code and it works with any type of url param passed

Comment: With empty .htaccess file also same result. I got only: Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
suPHP_Configpath /home/urlc/public_html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options -Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Message from my host:

The issue with http:// has been fixed. Our security feature mod_security was blocking the action. I have added an exception. Now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

It's not PHP - it's your httpd that returns 403. Please check it.